# How to add a left panel right next to a component using carbon components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svelte, carbon-components, carbon-components-svelte

I have a Sveltekit app and for my home route I want to display a table based on [carbon components](https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/). I want to filter the data displayed in the table by adding a left panel right next to the table. I'm basically looking for [their example](https://carbondesignsystem.com/patterns/filtering/#selecting-multiple-categories)

[image]

but I don't know how they solved it. I know the navbar has a navigation panel but this panel has nothing to do with the navigation and should only appear for my home route.

I tried to modify the official [codebox](https://codesandbox.io/s/header-with-nav-forked-40phf3?file=/src/index.js) sample to show what I have so far ( please have mercy, I've never used React before ). I hope the technology ( React / Vue / Svelte ) shouldn't matter.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import {
  Header,
  HeaderName,
  HeaderNavigation,
  HeaderMenuItem,
  Theme,
  Content,
  DataTable,
  TableContainer,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableHeader,
  TableBody,
  TableCell
} from "@carbon/react";

const App = () => (
  <Theme theme="g100">
    <Header>
      <HeaderName>Nav goes here</HeaderName>
      <HeaderNavigation>
        <HeaderMenuItem>Link 1</HeaderMenuItem>
      </HeaderNavigation>
    </Header>
    <Content>
      {/* TODO add sidebar for filters right next to the table */}

      <DataTable
        rows={[
          {
            id: 1,
            name: "First element"
          }
        ]}
        headers={[
          {
            key: "name",
            header: "Name"
          }
        ]}
      >
        {({ rows, headers, getHeaderProps, getTableProps }) => (
          <TableContainer title="DataTable">
            <Table {...getTableProps()}>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  {headers.map((header) => (
                    <TableHeader {...getHeaderProps({ header })}>
                      {header.header}
                    </TableHeader>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {rows.map((row) => (
                  <TableRow key={row.id}>
                    {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                      <TableCell key={cell.id}>{cell.value}</TableCell>
                    ))}
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
        )}
      </DataTable>
    </Content>
  </Theme>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I thought about using a [Grid component](https://carbon-components-svelte.onrender.com/components/Grid) but then both columns get the same width and the grid comes with **a big** horizontal margin.

If the grid is the right component for the job, how can I tell the first column ( filters ) to use the width it needs and the second column ( table ) fills the rest?

Do you have any ideas how to setup a left panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Grid is the component intended for layout like this. It has various options to modify its behavior and should be configured to be responsive.

It has a max-width that is probably intended to aid with readability as long lines on larger screens are harder to process. This limit can be removed by setting `fullWidth`.

There also is some padding that can be removed via `noGutter`, `noGutterLeft` and `noGutterRight`. These exist for `Grid`, `Row` and `Column`.

The responsiveness of the grid system is documented in more detail in the [design system specification](https://carbondesignsystem.com/guidelines/2x-grid/overview/#breakpoints). The number of "virtual" columns is dependent on the screen size. This count ranges from 4 up to 16.

E.g. in this case you might want to set `sm={4}` so the column jumps to full-width above the table on small screens and set `md={2}` to take up less space otherwise.

```html
<Content>
    <Grid fullWidth noGutter>
        <Row>
            <Column sm={4} md={2}>
                <div class="panel">
                    Left Panel
                </div>
            </Column>
            <Column>Content</Column>
        </Row>
    </Grid>
</Content>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/85503d6ca11349ad81c6f8de1560fef5?version=3.55.1)